# Windows 8 audio driver not installed automatically issue

Tags: windows, windows-8, audio, drivers, sound-card

I have a desktop. Once I had a problem with my sound card (Internal), so I replaced it with a new one. Then I installed ubuntu and the sound drivers installed automatically.

Now I've just installed windows 8 and all drivers are automatically installed except the **audio drivers**. I've the Driver's CD but it only works in XP and Windows 7.

Even the System's in built "Device diagnostic" doesn't work and windows 8 doesn't update the sound drivers automatically.

Are there any third party drivers which I can install in my system?

[Here is the picture](http://s29.postimg.org/6ymnbkq7b/DSC_0029.jpg)  of the Sound card:

[image]

Comment: Is there any label on the sound card? What does it say?

Comment: No there is not any lables. But as far as i remember in ubuntu, the automatically download driver's name was something like "yamaha sound driver"

Comment: Can you post a link to a picture of the card? Someone might recognise it.

Comment: I've posted the link in the Edited Question.

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried so far?

Drivers are never fun if they don't work the first time. I have spent months searching for the right drivers for certain laptops. I would advise that you try not to install too many 3rd party programs that claim to fix driver problems, as several of them are just Adware and Malware.

First I would try opening Device Manager and see what information if any is shown in there.

1. Try uninstalling the existing driver
2. Shut down and remove the sound card
3. Reboot without the sound card in there
4. Shut it down and install the card and boot back up.

This will delete any conflicting drivers and should display what sound card you have in the device manager information.

If this doesn't help you could try seeing if anything is shown in the device manager relevant to the sound card and posting what information it says.